# PayPal - Transfer amount from admin PayPal to User's debit/credit card

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

We have implemented Implicit Adaptive Payment (to transfer amounts from the admin PayPal account to User's PayPal account) and Explicit Adaptive Payment (to transfer amounts from User to User's account) using the Classic API and Rest API respectively.

This was all about PayPal to PayPal transfer, but There is a requirement to transfer the amount from admin's PayPal account to User's debit/credit cards.

Is there any API we can consume in order to implement the same?

Answer (score 0):

[DoNonReferencedCredit](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/) will allow you to credit funds to a debit/credit card.